# Regex for matching double quote but not pair of double quote

Tags: excel, regex

In Excel VBA regular expresson, how can match a double quote but need to ignore pair of double qoute? Thanks all.

Tried lookahead, lookbehind that might not meet the target.
Such as `^(?!.*"".*).*".*$`
This will ignore 2 or more double quote even 3 or 5. Which is not expected because it is not a pair.

Match

- `123"456`
- `123"456"789`
- `123"""456"""789`

Don't match

- `123""456`
- `123""456""789`
- `123456789`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `^(?!.*"").*".*`

Explanation:

`^`: Start of line

`(?!)`: Negative lookahead. Check to see if the string in the brackets matches. The match is cancelled if it does.

`.*""`: Any number of characters followed by two quote marks. The match is cancelled if this is found.

`.*".*`: The negative lookahead guarantees no double quotes are found, so just look for a single quote encased in any number of characters on either side.

Comment: Thanks. It works if there is 1 double quote, but not work if there is 3 double quote (added the case in question).

Comment: I just tried ^([^"]|"")*$ then inverse the result, it seems work but I don't know how it work.